# Gitlab.com CI: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: could not fetch content descriptor

Tags: php, gitlab, continuous-integration, runner

I have problem with gitlab-ci, parameters:

runner: shared runners (gitlab.com)

- access token: active
- remote repo (other gitlab.com repo): active
- remote docker image: exists

2 hours ago was fine..

Error:

```
#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s
#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 462B done
#2 DONE 0.1s
#3 [internal] load metadata for registry.gitlab.com/my_profile/nginx...
#3 ERROR: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: could not fetch content descriptor sha256:acfa0a241e8726b03df9ef0765ecddda7588cbc751cb07b53ac999046297dbda (application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json) from remote: not found
------
 > [internal] load metadata for registry.gitlab.com/my_profile/nginx-php:php-8.1:
------
registry.gitlab.com/my_profile/nginx-php:php-8.1: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: could not fetch content descriptor sha256:acfa0a241e8726b03df9ef0765ecddda7588cbc751cb07b53ac999046297dbda (application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json) from remote: not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```